# Which epoch could be considered as the best model according to its val_loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I read a couple of articles saying that the lower it is, the more accurate the model is. But the lowest value I obtained was at epoch 65. So I am unsure if it should be chosen as the best. Can someone take a look at the table of values I recorded in this [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EtgdiE8csO314xhOxm7ewvPY3dRICMruJQi8A18H19k/edit?usp=sharing) and tell me what they think?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are choosing the correct loss function and splitting your data according to the standards, it is straightforward:

Best model --> lowest val_loss --> **Epoch: 65**.

---

I believe you should learn more about the Basics of Machine Learning stuff and learn how to assess its performance.
([link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/), [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-to-the-bias-variance-trade-off-in-machine-learning/)...)